# I want to make a string key in array sequelize

Tags: javascript, regex, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm working in filter for the nested column , I'm using express , postgres, sequelize

that's the simple code
`` fielter[`$${key}$`] = +queryObj[key]; `` 
my goal is simply is make that index between two bracket in the object

**Result**
`{where: { '$article.id$': 9}}`
**DESIRED RESULT**
`{where: { ['$article.id$']: 9}}`

Comment: both are the same if we consider an object?

Comment: I received that message
``"missing FROM-clause entry for table \"article\``

Comment: and it worked normally if I type it manually (of course inside buckets )

Answer (score -1):

I included the model in the request

`Include:[{ model: db.Article, subQuery: false }],`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).